# How to change TableView frame color in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx, tableview

I couldn't find any info about how to change the frame color (**light-blue**) of the `TableView` element when it has **focus**. Anyone any ideas here?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The focus border coloring is controlled by two CSS attributes `-fx-focus-color` and `-fx-faint-focus-color`.

In most of the cases it is enough to use `-fx-focus-color` by for example adding this class into your CSS file:

```
.table-view {
    -fx-focus-color: red;
}
```

or directly in the Java code:

```
table.setStyle("-fx-focus-color: red;");
```

But also you can overwrite both like:

```
.table-view {
    -fx-focus-color: red;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: white;
}
```

**Background:**

By checking the default stylesheet ***modena.css***:

```
.table-view:focused{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-faint-focus-color, -fx-focus-color, -fx-control-inner-background; 
    -fx-background-insets: -1.4, -0.3, 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 2, 0, 0;
}
```

It finds out that these colors are used as background colors with various background-insets in the `:focused` pseudo-class. Therefore modifications on this pseudo-class can affect the focus border (for example the width of the border).

**Note 1:** If you want to remove the highlighting completely, you can set these attributes as `-fx-focus-color: transparent;`.

**Note 2:** To apply the same highlight-color to every `Node` you can use the `.root { -fx-focus-color: red; }` class in your CSS file.

Comment: Hi DVarga, I have set `.root { -fx-focus-color: red; }`. But only for TableView the color red is still not displayed. Other nodes such as Button, TextField etc.. all are in red. Any ideas?

Comment: Hm, it is quite interesting, as this is the "standard" solution. Did you set other CSS classes? Also, could you try to set also the `-fx-faint-focus-color` attribute?

Comment: Hi there, I just checked.`.table-view {
    -fx-background-insets: -3, 1, 2, 1;
} ` is causing the trouble. When I comment it out, the frame color is turning red alright. But I really need to set thickness of the colored frame. Do you know any other way to have both a thicker frame in red color?

Comment: You could try to add for example: `.table-view:focused{ -fx-background-insets: -3, -2, 1; }` as the two attributes are used in this pseudo class (feel free to play with the insets also in this class).

Comment: YES! Thanks to you, `.table-view:focused {
    -fx-faint-focus-color: red;
    -fx-background-insets: -3, 1, 2, 1;
}` is working great!

Answer (score 0):

### SOLUTION

Thanks to [DVarga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5966775/dvarga), I was able to come up with this solution:

Somehow `-fx-focus-color:` does not work in combination with `-fx-background-insets:`for the `TableView` component.

But `-fx-background-insets:` works with `-fx-faint-focus-color:`. Consequently my css solution looks like this:

```
.table-view:focused {
    -fx-faint-focus-color: red;
    -fx-background-insets: -3, 1, 2, 1;
}
```

Now its working perfectly! Hope we could help the future u.